# How to pass the value of radio button from the url and how to render in new page?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to pass the value to a new page like the following and render in the page

```
http://project/register.html?update=1&name=aaaaaa&fatherName=bns
```

Input fields can be easily saved and rendered using--

```
var var=getQueryParam("name");
$("inputFieldId").html(var);
```

Need to include radio button value as well.

How? Please help.

Comment: use var variablename,var $variablename.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each radio element an id then

```
$("#id").attr("value", "valueFromURL");
```